# SCSS file compiles in Visual Studio 2019 but not in 2022

Tags: sass, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, web-compiler

I have a number of import statements at the top of the SCSS file in a project I've inherited. Here are the relevant statements:

```
...
@import "node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass";
...
@import "node_modules/buefy/src/scss/buefy.scss";
...
```

Using Webcompiler, the SCSS file compiles in Visual Studio 2019. However, when I try to compile it in Visual Studio 2022 I get an error saying it can't find the bulma stylesheet. I tried adding "node_modules" to the includePath in the SASS section of compilerconfig.json.defaults. This seemed to work for the bulma stylesheet but I then got that same error on the buefy stylesheet. The files are definitely present (otherwise it wouldn't compile in VS2019).

Anyone any ideas? Is there a setting in Visual Studio 2022 that I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the extension webcompiler does not work with visual studio 2022 (not sure if it will be fixed)

Answer (score 2):

[Someone ported the extensions to VS2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Failwyn.WebCompiler64)

Note: I'm not the author of the port, or of the original extensions.

Comment: Worked great for me in 2022!

Comment: I still have the same problem in VS 2022 and the updated extension

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when attempting to compile a .scss file. I got it working by removing (or renaming) the temp folder for the WebCompiler extension:

1. Close VS2022
2. Go to C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Temp\
3. Remove or rename the "WebCompiler<current version>" folder
4. Open VS2022 - it should rebuild the "WebCompiler<current version>"
   folder
5. Right-click the .scss file in the solution, then Web Compiler
   > Compile file (or Re-compile file)